# reload nginx container on content change

Tags: docker, nginx, nginx-config

I'm setting up nginx server using Docker. If I add a new file/directory to all-html,is that content need to loaded to nginx dynamically(without reloading the nginx)?

I can able to load the new contents only If rebuilding the image again (without cache). is there any way to setup the nginx configuration to dynamically load the content without rebuilding the docker image?

Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y nginx
RUN rm /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

ADD nginx.conf /etc/nginx/

ADD web /usr/share/nginx/html/
ADD web /var/www/html/

RUN echo "daemon off;" >> /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
EXPOSE 90

CMD service nginx start
```

nginx.conf

```
worker_processes 1;

events { worker_connections 1024; }

http {
    include    mime.types;
    sendfile on;
    server {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html/;
        index index.html;
        server_name localhost;
        listen 90;
        location /all-html {
               autoindex on;
        }
    }

}
```

```
ls  web/
all-html    icons       index.html  mime.types
```

```
ls  web/all-html/
1.html  ntf.zip 2.html
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `VOLUME` to mount the web directory, so that the files will be in sync and Nginx dynamically load the content without rebuilding the docker image.

You can mount the volume in Dockerfile or even while starting the container like below.

```
-v web:/var/www/html/
```

Answer (score 1):

You can mount a host directory as a volume inside the container, make changes in the host directory (they will propagate inside the container) and then `docker exec ... nginx -s reload OR kill -s HUP`, is that the bash snippet you mentioned ? Or you can run another processus inside the container that will periodically check for changes and reload the nginx process.

Comment: nginx is able to read the content without reload? 
(if reload is the only solution, we can add a cron to see the content change)

Comment: Given your config file, you don't need to reload the server if you modify the content of `/usr/share/nginx/html/` (you can add/delete files/directories as you want) the server will take that into account, but you may need to delete cache to force the server load the new files. But if you change the configuration, I think you need to reload the server.